# How can (byte)Convert.ToChar(anyStringOfLengthOne) possibly throw an error?

Tags: c#, .net, string, char, byte

We have this rather simple code in a project:

```
string input = "Any string";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    string stringOfLengthOne = input.Substring(i, 1);
    byte value = (byte)Convert.ToChar(stringOfLengthOne);
    if (value == someValue)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The input is a string with characters usually read from a file that need to be processed depending on their byte value.

Unfortunately, we do not have the chance to debug this process step-by-step, we just need to make an educated guess what kind of string could cause

```
 (byte)Convert.ToChar(anyStringOfLengthOne)
```

in the code above to throw an "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error.

My thinking is that as soon as I have a string, it should always be possible to 1. pick a char and 2. convert it to a byte. Yet the error occurs.

Any ideas, hints? Or can someone even provide a string that throws this kind of error?

Comment: Hope you know the range of [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693.aspx)

Comment: I do. Yet I fail to create a string that throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Characters in .Net are 16 bits (short/ushort) in length.

The default project settings for C# means that the cast would work and will just ignore the higher bits for any character that is larger than 255, i.e. like using `(byte) (c & 0xff)`.

However, if you are using checked arithmetic, trying to cast a char that is greater than 255 will result in an ArithmeticOverflowExcetion.

The default setting for arithmetic can be set to checked/unchecked in the project's build settings.

## Example

```
char c = (char) 300;
byte b = unchecked ((byte) c);
Console.WriteLine (b);

// Result: 44

char c = (char) 300;
byte b = checked ((byte) c);
Console.WriteLine (b);

// Result: ArithmeticOverflowExcetion
```

## Alternative

Alternativly, you could compare the characters directly.

For example to test if a character is 0-9

```
char c = input[i];
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    // do something
}
```

You can even compare a char to an int

```
char c = input[i];
if (c >= 48 && c <= 57) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not aware that we are using checked arithmetic in our project settings. I'll check (sic!).

Comment: Now (char)556 would also result in 44 , not sure if the OP wants just to continue with the overflowing ....

Comment: indeed, if overflow is meant to be allowed I'd add an explicit `c & 0xff` to make it obvious, otherwise I'd have an explicit `if (c > 255) { /* handle error */ }`

Comment: Thanks for the code improvements (btw, it wasn't even our code)! However, I still can't make the code fail...

Comment: Input a character that has a value greater than 255, musical trebel clef is always good at causing trouble since it also requires 2 utf-16 characters to encode, `(utf-32) "\U0001D11E"` or `(utf-16) "\uD834\uDD1E"` you can enter it using `alt+1D11E`

Comment: I still can't produce an error (mainly, I believe, because string doesn't have an encoding and simply interprets a single byte), but your answer is the most elaborate, and in addition to that provides a possible cause by hinting towards the checked/unchecked setting.

Answer (score 1):

Why not access input[i] instead of using a Substring and Convert?

EDIT:

Oh, oh, sorry, I missed it. Characters are 16 bit in .NET (Unicode), so it's very reasonable you can't convert a char to a byte if you're using non English characters. Try any Hebrew letter for instance.

Comment: Well the string as such doesn't have an encoding. If I add any non us-ascii character (tried a few wild ones), in my test code it still works well. I can't make it throw an exception.

Comment: Intriguing. There are so many crazy characters out there, it could be anything. Why don't you ask the user what the input was? The string your code gets is somehow related to something the user types, isn't it?

Comment: It's comes from a .txt file. There is no chance we can ask the user (for various reasons), so I wanted to tackle this matter theoretically - AND maybe get a good hint for a test scenario.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx)

> Each character in a string is defined by a Unicode scalar value, also
>   called a Unicode code point or the ordinal (numeric) value of the
>   Unicode character. Each code point is encoded by using **UTF-16**
>   encoding, and the numeric value of each element of the encoding is
>   represented by a Char object.

Byte is 8 bits, UTF-16 is 16 bits, this is why you get an error.

Comment: Thanks, but as Chris Chilvers writes correctly the higher bits for characters > 255 are ignored. The string type shouldn't know about the encoding - at least that's what my admittedly limited knowledge about these issues suggests.